# How to use delimiter on column where some instances do not have the delimiter, python

Tags: python, pandas, split, delimiter

I have a column called sub, that I want to split into sub_1 and sub_2.

sub example looks like this:

```
banana/apple, 
banana,
apple
```

where some records have the delimiter '/' and some don't.

What I am trying to do is:
if there is a delimiter like in the first example above, split so:
sub_1 -> banana and sub_2 -> apple

if there is no delimiter like in the second two examples, then it would look like:
sub_1 -> banana
sub_1 -> apple

I tried this code:

```py
df[['sub_1', 'sub_2']] = df['sub'].str.split('/', expand=True)
```

However I get this error:

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

which I am guessing is because how some columns do not have a delimiter, wondering if there is a quick way to default that issue to the first column if anyone here has run into this issue before.

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: That code would work fine if you had a dataframe with rows of strings like you have. So the fact that you're getting an error means there's something wrong/misrepresented about your data. Therefore, until you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post, it's pretty much impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe looks like this:

```py
>>> df
            sub
0  banana/apple
1        banana
2         apple
```

Then you just need to split with `expand`:

```py
>>> df[["sub_1", "sub_2"]] = df["sub"].str.split("/", expand=True)

>>> df
            sub   sub_1  sub_2
0  banana/apple  banana  apple
1        banana  banana   None
2         apple   apple   None
```

Or, using `pd.Series`, if you want `NaN`s:

```py
>>> df["sub"].str.split("/").apply(pd.Series)
            sub   sub_1  sub_2
0  banana/apple  banana  apple
1        banana  banana    NaN
2         apple   apple    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"sub": ["banana/apple", "banana", "apple"]})

res = df.join(df.pop("sub").str.split("/", expand=True))
res.columns = ["sub_1", "sub_2"]

print(res)

    sub_1  sub_2
0  banana  apple
1  banana   None
2   apple   None
```